Does an iTunes backup also backup the "Recently Deleted" album and folder?
Assume that iCloud backups on an iPhone/iPad are disabled. Assume that there are files in the "Recently Deleted" folder and that there are photos in the "Recently Deleted" album. If one creates a normal backup of the iPhone/iPad, are the contents of the "Recently Deleted" album and the "Recently Deleted" folder backed up, too? What about if one creates an encrypted backup of the iPhone/iPad?

Yes, the Recently Deleted photos are still in the backup. They're present in both encrypted and not-encrypted backups. The photo files are still in their usual spot in the backup CameraRollDomain Media/DCIM.
